# Keep blender rendered high quality images during video creation (ffmpeg)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I created an animation in Blender and exported each frame as **high quality** picture. However, putting them together using *ffmpeg* reduces the quality (I also tried the video export from Blender but I am not an expert in video codecs and all related topics). I converted the single frames into a video by using the following command:

`ffmpeg -f image2 -i %4d.png -r 60 -crf 0 -vcodec libx264 blenderVideo.mp4`

The resulting frame from the video is given in the picture below. As one can see, the shining rings are clearly visible but in the original picture it is completely smooth. Any idea how to overcome this problem? Maybe it is stupid to think that I can get the original qualities. Probably, if I upload it somewhere, it gets compressed in any case and it is not worth to investigate into that topic too much. However, I am interested and there are specialists out who can directly tell if it is worth or not.

[image: Compressed image via ffmpeg]

Comment: What is the final destination of the video? YouTube?

Comment: Yes. Exactly, I will add some audio and it will be an introduction video for all of my new videos.

Comment: You can give YouTube the original PNG files with `ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %4d.png -i audio.mp3 -c copy output.mkv` (if it's real short duration as the resulting file size might be huge) or `ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %4d.png -i audio.wav -crf 0 -c:v libx264rgb output.mp4` (for lossless RGB H.264 for something smaller but same quality). You'll avoid the RGB to YUV colorspace conversion and chroma subsampling and make YouTube do it instead. I don't know what they use for that, but maybe the result will look better than FFmpeg's swscale.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Even with the libx264rgb. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use libx264rgb:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %4d.png -i audio.wav -crf 0 -c:v libx264rgb output.mp4
```

You'll avoid the RGB to YUV colorspace conversion and chroma subsampling and make YouTube do it instead. I don't know what they use for that, but maybe the result will look better than FFmpeg's swscale.